# Why 'segmentation fault' occurs in the following C code

Tags: c

```
$hoho

a

b

abcd

$hoho | lala

segmentation fault
```

lala.c 
-->

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv){

printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

...
}
```

then, how can I use the std_input a, b and abcd

Comment: `argv` contains *command line arguments*, not STDIN.

Comment: `$hoho | xargs lala`

Answer (score 1):

In your `lala.c` (I hope the actual files are not named like this),

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

you're using `argv[1]` without checking it's validity. It can very well be `NULL` or uninitalized or non-existant. This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So, before using `argv[n]`, you have to always put a check like

```
if (argc < (n+1))
  //abort
else
  //use upto argv[n]
```

Other than that, as pointed out my Mr. **@Iharob Al Asimi**,  `char* argv` should be `char* argv[]` or `char ** argv`. (I believe that's more of a typo in your code, though).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `main()` has the wrong signature. It's not

   ```
   int main(int argc, char* argv)
   ```

   it's

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   ```

   or equivalently

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   ```
2. You are trying to print a `char` with the `"%s"` specifier, the `printf()` function tries to read a string and interprets the `char` value as an address because it's expecting a `char` pointer, this leads to undefined behavior<sup>1</sup> and hence to the problem.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Please read the link posted by @[SouravGhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) as well as his answer which is also good advice.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change the line

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
```

This will be valid if you want multiple arguements. Secondly check for the argument count before printing it. So replace the following line

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

with

```
if(argc > 1)
  printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```